# Rally Python API

Tags: python, rally, pyral

I am trying to get to my company's Rally subscription using the Python toolkit following the instructions at http://developer.rallydev.com/help/python-toolkit-rally-rest-api

However, I am running into the following error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test_prog.py", line 12, in
>   
>       rally = Rally(server, user, password, workspace=workspace, project=project)   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyral\restapi.py", line 184, in
>   **init**
>       self.contextHelper.check(self.server)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyral\context.py", line 153, in check
>       raise RallyRESTAPIError(problem) pyral.context.RallyRESTAPIError: hostname: 'https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/login.op  ' non-existent or
>   unreachable

Does anyone know if there are any subscription settings that would control/restrict access to it using the pyral Rally REST API?

I am using pyral 0.9.1 with requests 0.9.3 and certifi 0.0.8 using Python 2.7 on a Windows 7 platform.

Any help/insight is highly appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: Figured that updating to 0.13.5 requests package does the trick. Now I am able to connect to the server, but failing at authentication phase with a 401 error code.

Comment: I'd still be interested to understand if you're using a Proxy. The 401 may be coming from your proxy server, and not from Rally.

Comment: No, there is no proxy used to access the Rally server or the Internet. It is a https webserver that hosts the Rally though. Not sure if it matters.

Comment: Can you check your server url connection string in your source code? For pyral, it should be `https://rally1.rallydev.com` - there's not a `/slm` on the end like there is for the rally ruby api, for instance.

Comment: @MarkW My config file is the following:

SERVER    = https://rally1.rallydev.com
USER      = myEmail@CompanyName.com
PASSWORD  = myPassword

Once I make the URL a https, I get the non-existent or unreachable server error. If I drop the https, it rightly errors out on 401, possibly because of un-encrypted username and password over the SSL connection. I am not so sure where the problem is anymore. Btw, thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: This acts a lot like a proxying issue - i.e. access via http generates the 401, but https it cannot connect or find the server. Some proxies accept requests over http and then do https over http on the back end for actual request handling. I'd check with your IT department about whether or not your network uses a proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you access the internet through a proxy server? You may wish to check with your IT department about this.

Unfortunately, there are some limitations in the requests and urllib packages (upon which pyral relies) handle HTTP over HTTPS.

The requests package machinery does not correctly support HTTPS over HTTP which is exactly what a proxy must do to connect to Rally since all URLs are HTTPS based. The maintainers of the the requests package are aware of this situation and there are code fixes for the underlying dependency (urllib3) that are currently being evaluated for inclusion.

When the requests package incorporates the code to support proxy correctly, Rally's developers plan to incorporate that code and will provide the configuration step (setting an environment variable) for pyral to work in a proxied environment.

Answer (score 1):

pyral use ping to check if the server is available so it won;t work over proxy till you update context.py in the pyral source code (comment out lines 146-150)

```
###reachable, problem = Pinger.ping(target_host)
###if not reachable:
###if not problem:
###problem = "host: '%s' non-existent or unreachable"  %    target_host
###raise RallyRESTAPIError(problem)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to integrate CA Agile Central with your python API, if this error occurs.

```
Target Rally host: 'https://rally1.rallydev.com' non-existent or unreachable
```

try using 'rally1.rallydev.com' not 'https://rally1.rallydev.com'

```
rally = Rally(server="rally1.rallydev.com", user,
                      password,
                      workspace,
                      project)
```

Using pyral version: 1.4.0