# pyral module got an unexpected keyword argument 'verify'

Tags: python, rally, pyral

I am new to the `pyral` module. I tried the demo code and I cannot get past the call to Rally.

```
rally = Rally(server, user, password, workspace=workspace, project=project)
```

I also tried.

```
rally = Rally(server, user, password, workspace=workspace, project=project, verify_ssl_cert=False)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What was the error for the first line ?

Comment: Do you know if your site is using a proxy server for internet access? If so, you may wish to check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770283/rally-python-api/11779016#11779016

Answer (score 0):

If your site uses a proxy server for internet access, you may wish to check out this answer: [Rally Python API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770283/rally-python-api/)